# Adding new columns to a Winforms DataGridView via code

Tags: c#, .net, datagridview

I'm trying to add N number of columns for each days of a given month:

```
var daysCount = DateTime.DaysInMonth(DateTime.Now.Year, month);

for (int i = 1; i <= daysCount; i++)
{
    dataGridView1.Columns.Add(new DataGridViewColumn() { HeaderText = i.ToString() });
}
```

I'm getting this error:

> At least one of the DataGridView
>   control's columns has no cell
>   template.

Answer (score 14):

When you create a new datagridview column it's pretty blank.  You will need to set the [celltemplate](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridviewcolumn.celltemplate.aspx) of the column so that it knows what controls to show for the cells in the grid.  Alternatively I think if you use some of the stronger typed columns (DataGridViewTextBoxColumn)  then you might be ok.

Answer (score 10):

The problem stems from your `DataGridViewColumn.CellTemplate` not being set.

For this scenario a `DataGridViewTextBoxCell` as the `CellTemplate` should suffice.

```
       var daysCount = DateTime.DaysInMonth(DateTime.Now.Year, 1);

        for (int i = 1; i <= daysCount; i++)
        {
            dataGridView1.Columns.Add(new DataGridViewColumn() { HeaderText = i.ToString(), CellTemplate = new DataGridViewTextBoxCell() });
        }
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to specify first whether it's a textbox column or combobox column
Try this it will work

```
var daysCount = DateTime.DaysInMonth(DateTime.Now.Year, month);

for (int i = 1; i <= daysCount; i++)
{
    dataGridView1.Columns.Add(new DataGridViewTextBoxColumn() { HeaderText = i.ToString() });
}
```

Answer (score 1):

set your table and add needed columns.
then use:

```
var daysCount = DateTime.DaysInMonth(DateTime.Now.Year, 1);

for (int i = 0; i <= daysCount; i++)
        {
          i = dataGridView1.Rows.Add(new DataGridViewRow());


                        dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells["YourNameCell"].Value = i.ToString();

       }
```

Frist row is 0, not 1. probabily your error are these.