# How to select visible columns in Datagridview bound to DataTable

Tags: vb.net, winforms, data-binding, datagridview

I have these fields on *Customer* `DataTable`: *ID,title,Name,Addrs,email,Fax* and this code to bind the `DataGridView`:

```
Dim sql As String = "SELECT * FROM Customers"
Dim daHeader As New SqlDataAdapter(sql, Conn)
daHeader.Fill(dsNota, "Customers")
dgvHeader.DataSource = dsNota.Tables("Customers")
```

How do I view *title,name,addrs* data in  `DataGridView` **without** changing the SQL string to:

```
"SELECT title,Name,Addrs FROM Customer"
```

Comment: You should avoid `SELECT *` syntax. Always specify the columns you need in every query.

Comment: in my case,,there is a column which does not need to displayed,,but thanks for your suggestion..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So if you don't want to modify your query string (as @Neolisk noticed this is generally a bad practice to use `Select *` but this is another debat), and so you get more columns than what you want to display:

**Solution1** (Ideal if there are a lot of columns in datatable and you want to **display** just some of them)

1. You need to set [AutoGenerateColumns](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridview.autogeneratecolumns%28v=vs.80%29.aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=vb) property to false.
   Default is True, so DataGridView will create a column for all columns in the datatable.
2. Then, you add a `DatagridiviewColumn` for each column you want to display.
   To avoid to have to add a [celltemplate](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridviewcolumn.celltemplate.aspx) for the  DatagriviewColumn (see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4832655/adding-new-columns-to-a-winforms-datagridview-via-code)) you would prefer to add a strongly typed column ([DataGridViewTextBoxColumn](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridviewtextboxcolumn.aspx) for example in order to display `String` values). In order to bind the column with the source, you set the [DataPropertyName](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridview.columns%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) property, that needs to match with the `ColumnName` of the column in`DataTable`.

So code would be:

```
dgvheader.AutoGenerateColumns = False
dgvHeader.Columns.Add(New DataGridViewTextBoxColumn() With {.HeaderText = "Title", .DataPropertyName = "title"}) 
dgvHeader.Columns.Add(New DataGridViewTextBoxColumn() With {.HeaderText = "Name", .DataPropertyName = "Name"}) 
dgvHeader.Columns.Add(New DataGridViewTextBoxColumn() With {.HeaderText = "Adresse", .DataPropertyName = "Addrs"}) 
dgvHeader.DataSource = dsNota.Tables("Customers")
```

---

**Solution2** (Ideal if there are a lot of columns in datatable, and you want to **Hide** just some of them, and so you want to keep the benefit of [AutoGenerateColumns](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridview.autogeneratecolumns%28v=vs.80%29.aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=vb))

1. Set [AutoGenerateColumns](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridview.autogeneratecolumns%28v=vs.80%29.aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=vb) property to true (or do nothing since
   default is True)
2. Hook the [DataGridView.DataBindingComplete](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridview.databindingcomplete.aspx) Event in order to hide some columns autogenerated:

   ```
   Private Sub dataGridView1_DataBindingComplete(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As DataGridViewBindingCompleteEventArgs) Handles dgvHeader.DataBindingComplete   
       With dgvHeader
           .Columns("Fax").Visible = False
       End With
   End Sub
   ```

Comment: Thanks Chris,,I'll try your suggestion,,

Answer (score 0):

If the gridview autogeneratecolumns attribute is set to true change it to false and then do as Raimond suggested. Example:

```
<asp:GridView ID="gvSearchResults" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False">
        <Columns>
                <asp:BoundField DataField="title" HeaderText="Title" />
        </Columns>
</asp:GridView>
```

Comment: The question does not have a reference to ASP. I would assume WinForms based on class name `DataGridView`.

Answer (score 0):

I know this post goes way back, but I had the same problem in C# and this is how I solved it which works really well.

**1 - Build a DataSet with your SQL query**

```
     private void LoadDS()
     {
         // this method gets data from my database
         // DS is a DataSet in the properties of my form
         DS = LoadData();
     }
```

**2 - Get the DataView filtered the way you want**

For this I use the **RowFilter** property of the DataView.
I created a GetFiltersToString() method that formats every filter control I have in a string that matches the RowFilter syntax (more information about the syntax [here](http://www.csharp-examples.net/dataview-rowfilter/), and msdn definition of RowFilter [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/system.data.dataview.rowfilter(v=vs.110).aspx))

```
    public void RefreshDGV()
    { 
        // Get the corresponding dataview
        DV = new DataView(DS.Tables[0], rowFilter, "SORTINGCOLUMN Desc", DataViewRowState.CurrentRows);
        // Display it in a datagridview
        DGV.DataSource = DV;
    }
```

I find that this solution allows user to change the filtering much more easily.

Answer (score -1):

You have to explicitly add the columns to your grid.

Comment: I think this should give the information: http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/CSASPNETGridView-5b16ce70