# How can i bind a generic List of custom classes to a datagridview and only show specific properties in VB.NET?

Tags: .net, vb.net, datagridview

I would like a way to present custom classes in a datagridview in a custom way that I have full control of. For example if I simply bind the List to the datagridview now, a column for each public property will be created. Even if I utilize the DataPropertyName property of the DataGridViewTextBoxColumn, additional columns for each additional property of the custom class is created.

I know that I can simply populate the datagridview myself, but even being a VB.NET beginner, I feel that that is not a good solution. Is it?

I think I remember that it is possible to implement some interface that helps specify exactly how a the class is represented in a datagridview control.

Can some one point me towards the best and most efficient solution?

Comment: Take a look at this answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/16744811/2387010

Comment: Thanks that definitely solves some of the problem. I'm however still interested in some way to be able to represent a custom class in a more custom way in a datagridview without having to create new properties just for this purpose in the custom class. As a beginner I can only think of creating a function in the custom class that returns a datagridviewrow filled specifically as I want with custom class data and column generation properties. But certainly there must be a better built in way to do it!

Comment: If I correctly understand what you want, yes you can create custom properties in base class, but this is not required. You should also consider using Datagridview events, for example [DataGridView.CellFormatting](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridview.cellformatting(v=vs.110).aspx) Event with which you could display custom datas based on others properties on your base class.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can make use of the [`Browsable` attribute](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.browsableattribute%28v=vs.95%29.aspx).

If you bind a List of the following class to a `DataGridView`

```
Class Person

    Public Property Name As String

    Public Property Department As String

    <System.ComponentModel.Browsable(False)>
    Public Property SomethingInternal As String

End Class
```

only the `Name` and `Department` column would be created.

Quick example:

```
Using f As New Form
    Dim g = New DataGridView With {
        .Dock = DockStyle.Fill,
        .DataSource = { New Person With 
                        { 
                            .Name = "Foobar", 
                            .Department = "BarFoo", 
                            .SomethingInternal = "Don't show this"
                        }}}
    f.Controls.Add(g)
    f.ShowDialog()
End Using
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

DataGridView have `AutoGenerateColumns` property which by default is `True`. Set it to `False` and specify the columns that you want under `DataGridView -> Columns` tag