# How to show specific columns value from MySQL database into DataGridView

Tags: c#, mysql, winforms, data-binding, datagridview

Suppose I have used the following MySQL query:

```
select * from userinfo;
```

In the database the following columns are available: *username*, *email*, *pass*, *secqu*, *secan*;
Now I want to show only the ***username***, and ***email*** columns value into my `DataGridView`.
Now My Question is: How can I do it?  Code like something `datagridview.rows[index]. ....` something like this is used, but I cannot remember. Can anyone help to do this?

N.B: Please do not reply with the following one:
    1. change the query into `[select username, email from userinfo;];`
    2. Change which columns will you want hide or not. As the other columns value are required so I need to use the query.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to select visible columns in Datagridview bound to DataTable](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16688760/how-to-select-visible-columns-in-datagridview-bound-to-datatable)

Comment: The answer is in your question than what you want? and what problem you are getting?

Answer (score 0):

if you don't want to specify the columns in your query and want to fill datagridview with `Select *` query then you have another option that you can hide columns from the `DataGridView`.

```
string[] strShowColumns = new String[] {"username", "email"};
for (int i=0; i < dgv.Columns.Count; i++)
{
    if (!strShowColumns.Contains(dgv.Columns[1].Name))
        dgv.Columns[i].Visible = false;
}
```